# What type should be used with async dispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-thunk

I am creating a project with TypeScript using React.
In an action file which is loginAction.tsx, I have a line like this:

```
export const login = (obj) => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
    });
    const response = await axios.post(`/api/login`, obj);
    if (response.data && response.data.status === 'success') {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: response.data
        });
    } else if (response.data && response.data.status === 'failure') {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
            payload: response.data
        });
    }
}
```

This works fine in JavaScript. But in TypeScript, I am not sure what return types I should use and how I can use them. I have tried in some ways but none of them are getting accepted. Every time I am getting an error in the line "export const login = (obj) => async dispatch =>". Can anyone help me to write this portion correctly in TypeScript?

PS: I tried to use the first line like this:

```
interface ILoginObject {
    email: string,
    password: string
}

export const login = (loginObject: ILoginObject) => async dispatch => {}
```

But it says, "Missing return type on function" and shows the error by underlining the "async dispatch =>" portion.

Comment: Let's start by posting the exact error you are getting :)

Comment: return `void`.  .

Comment: I tried to use "export const login = (loginObject: ILoginObject) => async dispatch =>". There, I got an error "Missing return type on function". And the ILoginObject is: interface ILoginObject {
    email: string,
    password: string
}

Comment: Can you please write the first line by adding the return type? I am not sure where I should add the "void" return type. Adding it after "dispatch" does not work. @RajdeepDebnath

Comment: My answer on your other question should make this a non-issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67943707/10431574  But the answer here would involve importing the dispatch type from redux-thunk.

Answer (score -1):

```
interface ILoginObject {
    email: string,
    password: string
}

interface ILoginDispatch {
    type: string,
    payload?: {
        success? : boolean,
        status?: number,
        message?: string,
        user?: {
            id: string,
            email: string
        },
        access_token?: string,
        expires_in?: string
    }
}

export const userLogin = (loginObject: ILoginObject) => async (dispatch: Dispatch<ILoginDispatch>): Promise<void> => {
    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_REQUEST
    });

    const response = await axios.post(`/api/login`, loginObject);

    if(response.data && response.data.access_token) {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: response.data
        });
    }
    else {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
            payload: response.data
        });
    }
}
```