# How to use this.props.action function in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

My authActions.tsx file looks like this:

```
import {
    LOGIN_REQUEST,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAILURE
} from './types';

import axios from 'axios';
import { Dispatch } from 'react';

interface ILoginObject {
    email: string,
    password: string
}

interface ILoginDispatch {
    type: string,
    payload?: {
        success? : boolean,
        status?: number,
        message?: string,
        user?: {
            id: string,
            email: string
        },
        access_token?: string,
        expires_in?: string
    }
}

export const userLogin = (loginObject: ILoginObject) => async (dispatch: Dispatch<ILoginDispatch>): Promise<void> => {
    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_REQUEST
    });

    const response = await axios.post(`/api/login`, loginObject);

    if(response.data && response.data.access_token) {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: response.data
        });
    }
    else {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
            payload: response.data
        });
    }
}
```

And my Login.tsx file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { userLogin } from '../store/actions/authActions';

interface IProps {
    auth: {
        payload?: {
            success? : boolean,
            status?: number,
            message?: string,
            user?: {
                id: string,
                email: string
            },
            access_token?: string,
            expires_in?: string
        }
    }
}

interface IState {
    email: string,
    password: string
}

interface IEvent {
    target: HTMLInputElement
}

class Login extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

    state: IState = {
        email: "",
        password: ""
    }

    onEmailChange = (e: IEvent): void => {
        this.setState({
            email: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onPasswordChange = (e: IEvent): void => {
        this.setState({
            password: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onSubmit = (): void => {
        //
    }

    render(): JSX.Element {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Email
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="email" onChange={e => this.onEmailChange(e)} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Password
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="password" name="password" onChange={e => this.onPasswordChange(e)} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IProps) => {
    return {
        auth: state.auth
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { userLogin })(Login);
```

Now, I want to post a request using the "login" action inside the "onSubmit = () => {}" function. In JavaScript, this can be done by simply writing

```
return this.props.userLogin({email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password}).then(() => {
    // Something
})
```

But as it is TypeScript, the above code is not working and the "userLogin" function needs to be defined earlier. I tried to add "userLogin: () => void" to the "IProps" interface but I got an error message "Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'" for using the function and the code doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and switch to a function component.  Of course this can be typed properly, but it's much easier with the `useDispatch` hook.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is illogical because you are using the type `IProps` as the type for both:

- The props of the `Login` component
- The root state of your Redux store passed as an argument to `mapStateToProps`

You are expecting your component to take a prop `userLogin` which is a `function`.  This function is not a property of your Redux store state and therefore **it cannot possibly be true that the Redux state and the component props share the same type.**

If you fix the `IProps` to accurately represent the component props then you will have problems with `mapStateToProps` and the react-redux `connect` HOC because they are using `(state: IProps)`.  You have already discovered that in your replies to @Kakiz's answer.

---

You should not need to determine your redux state type in this component's file because that type is global.  The react-redux docs [recommend](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types) that you infer the  `RootState` type from your `store` variable, like this:

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

You put that line in the file where you create the store import the `RootState` type wherever you need it, like in `mapStateToProps`.

Their excellent guide on usage with TypeScript includes a whole section on [Typing the `connect` higher order component](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component), though they recommend using function components and hooks instead as these are much easier to type properly.

---

Don't be afraid to `export` types and reuse them.  The `ILoginObject` defined in your actions file is identical to the `IState` defined in your component.  Your `IProps` and `ILoginDispatch` have major duplications as well.

I often find it easier to write simple event handlers inline because then you avoid needing to type the `e` argument.

---

You need the TypeScript types to know that you have redux-thunk middleware installed in order to for it to know that dispatching an action will return a `Promise`, since this is not the default behavior.

The `userLogin` thunk itself can be simplified with the [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) function from the official Redux Toolkit.  This will also handle errors in the `axios.post` request itself, which you aren't currently catching.  It's also a good candidate for [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview), which just got integrated into Redux Toolkit.

---

Here's a better setup for your component, which is completely type-safe although there are no types anywhere.  Everything is inferred.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { unwrapResult } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { userLogin } from "../store/slice";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "../store";

// no props needed anymore
export default function Login() {
  // not sure where you actually use this
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = () => {
    dispatch(userLogin({ email, password }))
      .then(unwrapResult) // explained here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions
      .then((data) => alert(`logged in user ${data.user}`))
      .catch((error) => alert(`login error: ${error.message}`));
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <label>
          Email
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          Password
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

That is based on the following setup of store:

```
import { AnyAction, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  TypedUseSelectorHook,
  useDispatch as _useDispatch,
  useSelector as _useSelector
} from "react-redux";
import { logger } from "./middleware";
import auth from "./slice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth
  }
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export type Action = AnyAction;

export const useDispatch: () => AppDispatch = _useDispatch;

export const useSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = _useSelector;
export default store;
```

And reducer/actions:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export interface AuthData {
  success?: boolean;
  status?: number;
  message?: string;
  user?: {
    id: string;
    email: string;
  };
  access_token?: string;
  expires_in?: string;
}

export interface ILoginObject {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export const userLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/Login",
  async (loginObject: ILoginObject, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const response = await axios.post<AuthData>(`/api/login`, loginObject);

    if (response.data && response.data.access_token) {
      // returned value is the success payload
      return response.data;
    } else {
      // alternatively, can throw an Error
      return rejectWithValue(response.data);
    }
  }
);

const initialState: AuthData = { success: false };

const authSlice = createSlice({
  initialState,
  name: "auth",
  // reducers creates both actions and reducer cases
  reducers: {
    logout: (state, action) => {
      // clears the state and replaces with the initial state
      return initialState;
    }
  },
  // extraReducers adds reducer cases for existing actions
  extraReducers: (builder) =>
    builder
      .addCase(userLogin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        // TODO - this replaces the entire state, probably not what you actually want
        return action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(userLogin.rejected, (state, action) => {
        // TODO
      })
      .addCase(userLogin.pending, (state, action) => {
        // TODO - what is the correct number?
        state.status = 0;
      })
});

export const { logout } = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

You'll want to fill in some blanks in the reducer.

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-typescript-user-login-o1yy5?file=/src/components/App.tsx)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a huge help. But I am still confused about the lines "import auth from './slice';" and
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth
  }
});

What am I supposed to keep in "auth" then?

Comment: ‘./slice’ is just what I called the file which has the export default with the reducer in it.  Check out the link to the CodeSandbox, it has the complete setup  https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-typescript-user-login-o1yy5

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling `this.props.login(...).then(...)`, I assume `login` should return a Promise. You just need to type it as such in your `IProps` interface. Additionally, it looks like it's expected to take an argument containing `email` and `password`, so you should type that as well.

```
interface IProps {
  login: (credentials: { email: string; password: string; }) => Promise<void>;
}
```

Comment: As my function is "userLogin", I tried this: userLogin: ({ email: string; password: string; }) => Promise<void>. I got some errors. First one is the arrow. It says, " ';' expected ". Second one is the Promise. It says, "'Promise', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type."

Comment: Forgot to provide the argument name, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the function returns void, it means you're returning nothing, you can't get the property `then`. You need to return a `Promise`

```
interface IProps {
    auth: {
        payload?: {
            success? : boolean,
            status?: number,
            message?: string,
            user?: {
                id: string,
                email: string
            },
            access_token?: string,
            expires_in?: string
        }
    };
    login: () => Promise<void>;
}
```

Comment: Could you please show me how and where to do that?

Comment: When I use "return this.props.login().then(() => { // Some code })", I get this error:

Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void'

Comment: do you ever need to return `this.props.login`? considering the return type of onSubmit, which is void, you shouldn't return anything

Comment: My function is "userLogin()". So, I have used "userLogin: () => Promise;". But I get this error: "Generic type 'Promise<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)".

Comment: Also, the last line "export default connect(mapStateToProps, { userLogin })(Login)", returns a bunch of errors after adding the function. One of the errors is: Argument of type 'typeof Login' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<{ auth: { payload?: { success?: boolean | undefined; status?: number | undefined; message?: string | undefined; user?: { id: string; email: string; } | undefined; access_token?: string | undefined; expires_in?: string | undefined; } | undefined; }; } & { ...; }, ClassAttributes<...> & IProps>>'.

Comment: this is a warning. Just give your promise a generic type like `Promise<ILoginProps>`. This type will be the result of the promise, example: `yourPromise.then(res => res.data);` res will have the generic type

Comment: Okay. But what about these errors? The errors are too long, so I am adding them in several comments.

Comment: Argument of type 'typeof Login' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<{ auth: { payload?: { success?: boolean | undefined; status?: number | undefined; message?: string | undefined; user?: { id: string; email: string; } | undefined; access_token?: string | undefined; expires_in?: string | undefined; } | undefined; }; } & { ...; }, ClassAttributes<...> & IProps>>'.

Comment: Type 'typeof Login' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Matching<{ auth: { payload?: { success?: boolean | undefined; status?: number | undefined; message?: string | undefined; user?: { id: string; email: string; } | undefined; access_token?: string | undefined; expires_in?: string | undefined; } | undefined; }; } & { ...; }, ClassAttributes<...> & IProps>...'.

Comment: Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'Matching<{ auth: { payload?: { success?: boolean | undefined; status?: number | undefined; message?: string | undefined; user?: { id: string; email: string; } | undefined; access_token?: string | undefined; expires_in?: string | undefined; } | undefined; }; } & { ...; }, ClassAttributes<...> & IProps>' is not assignable to type 'IProps | Readonly<IProps>'.

Comment: Type 'Matching<{ auth: { payload?: { success?: boolean | undefined; status?: number | undefined; message?: string | undefined; user?: { id: string; email: string; } | undefined; access_token?: string | undefined; expires_in?: string | undefined; } | undefined; }; } & { ...; }, ClassAttributes<...> & IProps>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<IProps>'.

Comment: Types of property 'userLogin' are incompatible.
            Type '(loginObject: ILoginObject) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<ILoginProps>'

Comment: Those errors are because you're *also* using `IProps` as the type for your Redux store state.  I'll write another answer explaining it.